# Force linker to find stdc++ library in non-standard directory

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, ld

I've read **a lot** of guidance that says the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is searched before anything else, but one of my .so libraries is linking with `libtdc++.so.6` in `/usr/lib64`.

```
ldd mylib.so:
...
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f82abd18000)
...
```

I want `mylib.so` to link with `libstdc++.so.6` in another location, like `/apps/gcc_4.8.0/lib/libstdc++.so.6`

So I add `/apps/gcc_4.8.0/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which ***does not*** have `/usr/lib64` in it, but it still doesn't find it there.

If I add:

```
setenv LD_PRELOAD /apps/gcc_4.8.0/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

to my environment, there are no more linker errors. Yay, but that doesn't solve the problem. Users downstream aren't going to want to depend on this library being in the proper place. WHY ISN"T LD_LIBRARY_PATH BEING SEARCHED FIRST!?!

Answer (score 0):

It should work with the `Wl,--rpath=/apps/gcc_4.8.0/lib/libstdc++.so.6` compiler switch.

**Update:** If you need also the new loader use this compiler switch: `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=<path-to-the-new-dynamic-linker>`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me. I continue to get the runtime error, and the linker (or maybe the loader?) continues to look in /urs/lib64. Only the LD_PRELOAD has worked so far.

Comment: @KyleEnglish I updated my answer